# What is the most efficient way to compare two QStringList in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qstringlist

I have two String Lists and I already have a function that compares two lists to find out which elements of list 2 do not exist in list 1. This block of code works, but maybe it is not the best way to achieve it, there are any other way to get the same result without performing so many iterations with nested loops?

```
QStringList list1 = {"12420", "23445", "8990", "09890", "32184", "31111"};
QStringList list2 = {"8991", "09890", "32184", "34213"};
QStringList list3;

for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); ++i) {
    bool exists = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); ++j) {
        if(list2[i] == list1[j]){
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!exists) list3.append(list2[i]);
}

qDebug() << list3;
```

output: `("8991", "34213")`

Perhaps this small example does not seem like a problem since the lists are very small. But there might be a case where both lists contain a lot of data.

I need to compare these two lists because within my app, every time a button is clicked, it fetches an existing dataset, then runs a function that generates a new data (including existing ones, such as a data refresh), so I need to get only those that are new and didn't exist before. It might sound like strange behavior, but this is how the app works and I'm just trying to implement a new feature, so I can't change this behavior.

Comment: First, I would add a `break` statement when you find a match. No reason to continue after that point. Other than that, unless the lists are sorted, you still need to iterate over every item in both lists.

Comment: Yes, you're right I forgot to include the `break` statement while editing the code, thanks. I ask this question because in Python, for example, we can create data frames with pandas to simulate an inner, left or right joins to get this kind of results without using nested loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you switch to `QSet<QString>`, your code snippet boils down to:

```
auto diff = set2 - set1;
```

If the input and output data structures *must* be QStringLists, you can still do the intermediate computation with QSets and still come out ahead:

```
auto diff = (QSet::fromList(list2) - QSet::fromList(list1)).toList();
```

Comment: This is a good answer as far as how simple the code becomes. I'm curious how the performance compares to the simple for-loop approach. But that's an exercise for the OP to figure out.

Comment: QSet is based on hashtables, so QSet::fromList is O(n). Set subtraction is again O(n), and toList is also O(n). Total picture is then something like O(n + m + n +n) = O(n) The nested for loops in the question are O(n*m). Of course big-Oh notation only applies once inputs start becoming large, so a 4-element list is not representative.